# Get amount per group with latest date in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table of monthly transactions for each project and its respective area (Revenue, cost...).

I need to get last amount by date (combination of ACCT_YR_NUM and ACCT_MO_NUM) for each of projects.

I already managed to get when was the last transaction done (column `LAST_DATE`) but I struggle to get its respective amount.

**MY CODE:**

```
WITH init AS (
    SELECT 
        f.PRJCT_ID,
        f.ACT_PLNRT_USD_AMT,
        f.RPRTG_AREA_NM,
        last_day(date(f.ACCT_YR_NUM || '-' || f.ACCT_MO_NUM  || '-15')) ACCT_DATE,
        MAX(last_day(date(f.ACCT_YR_NUM || '-' || f.ACCT_MO_NUM  || '-15'))) over (partition by f.PRJCT_ID, f.RPRTG_AREA_NM) AS LAST_DATE
    FROM my.table f
)

SELECT 
    *,
    MAX(ACT_PLNRT_USD_AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_DATE = LAST_DATE, RPRTG_AREA_NM, PRJCT_ID) AS MAX_DATE_AMT
FROM init 

ORDER BY 
    PRJCT_ID,
    RPRTG_AREA_NM,
    ACCT_DATE
```

**RESULT (WRONG):**

| PRJCT_ID | RPRTG_AREA_NM | ACT_PLNRT_USD_AMT | ACCT_DATE | LAST_DATE | MAX_DATE_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 009RR0S | BACKLOG | 2587543 | 6/30/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 2795163 |
| 009RR0S | BACKLOG | 2507543 | 9/30/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 2507543 |
| 009RR0S | EXPENSE | 1056 | 6/30/2022 | 6/30/2022 | 1056 |
| 009RR0S | REVENUE | 21120 | 6/30/2022 | 6/30/2022 | 21120 |
| 009RR0S | SIGNINGS | -202540 | 1/31/2021 | 1/31/2022 | -202540 |
| 009RR0S | SIGNINGS | -266500 | 1/31/2022 | 1/31/2022 | -266500 |
| 00GRQ6W | COST | 17169 | 1/31/2021 | 2/28/2021 | 17169 |
| 00GRQ6W | COST | -17169 | 2/28/2021 | 2/28/2021 | -17169 |

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

| PRJCT_ID | RPRTG_AREA_NM | ACT_PLNRT_USD_AMT | ACCT_DATE | LAST_DATE | MAX_DATE_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 009RR0S | BACKLOG | 2587543 | 6/30/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 2507543 |
| 009RR0S | BACKLOG | 2507543 | 9/30/2022 | 9/30/2022 | 2507543 |
| 009RR0S | EXPENSE | 1056 | 6/30/2022 | 6/30/2022 | 1056 |
| 009RR0S | REVENUE | 21120 | 6/30/2022 | 6/30/2022 | 21120 |
| 009RR0S | SIGNINGS | -202540 | 1/31/2021 | 1/31/2022 | -266500 |
| 009RR0S | SIGNINGS | -266500 | 1/31/2022 | 1/31/2022 | -266500 |
| 00GRQ6W | COST | 17169 | 1/31/2021 | 2/28/2021 | -17169 |
| 00GRQ6W | COST | -17169 | 2/28/2021 | 2/28/2021 | -17169 |

SOURCE SAMPLE TABLE (`my.table`):

| PRJCT_ID | RPRTG_AREA_NM | ACT_PLNRT_USD_AMT | ACCT_YR_NUM | ACCT_MO_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 009RR0S | BACKLOG | 2507543 | 2022 | 06 |
| 009RR0S | BACKLOG | 2507543 | 2022 | 09 |
| 009RR0S | EXPENSE | 1056 | 2022 | 06 |
| 009RR0S | REVENUE | 21120 | 2022 | 06 |
| 009RR0S | SIGNINGS | -202540 | 2021 | 01 |
| 009RR0S | SIGNINGS | -266500 | 2022 | 01 |
| 00GRQ6W | COST | 17169 | 2021 | 01 |
| 00GRQ6W | COST | -17169 | 2021 | 02 |

Comment: can you share the original data table and add more description to what you are looking for, for example what do you mean by :  the latest date ?

Comment: I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to enumerate rows in each group to assign row number 1 to a row with the latest date in this group and use this row as the only one in the `MAX` OLAP function.

```
WITH 
MY_TABLE (PRJCT_ID, RPRTG_AREA_NM, ACT_PLNRT_USD_AMT, ACCT_YR_NUM, ACCT_MO_NUM) AS
(
VALUES
  ('009RR0S', 'BACKLOG' , 2507543, '2022', '06')
, ('009RR0S', 'BACKLOG' , 2507543, '2022', '09')
, ('009RR0S', 'EXPENSE' ,    1056, '2022', '06')
, ('009RR0S', 'REVENUE' ,   21120, '2022', '06')
, ('009RR0S', 'SIGNINGS', -202540, '2021', '01')
, ('009RR0S', 'SIGNINGS', -266500, '2022', '01')
, ('00GRQ6W', 'COST'    ,   17169, '2021', '01')
, ('00GRQ6W', 'COST'    ,  -17169, '2021', '02')
)
, INIT AS
(
SELECT 
  F.*
, DATE (ACCT_YR_NUM || '-' || ACCT_MO_NUM || '-01') + 1 MONTH - 1 DAY AS ACCT_DATE
, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY PRJCT_ID, RPRTG_AREA_NM ORDER BY ACCT_YR_NUM DESC, ACCT_MO_NUM DESC) AS RN_
FROM MY_TABLE F
)
SELECT 
  PRJCT_ID, RPRTG_AREA_NM, ACT_PLNRT_USD_AMT, ACCT_DATE
, MAX (ACCT_DATE)                                  OVER (PARTITION BY PRJCT_ID, RPRTG_AREA_NM) AS LAST_DATE
, MAX (CASE RN_ WHEN 1 THEN ACT_PLNRT_USD_AMT END) OVER (PARTITION BY PRJCT_ID, RPRTG_AREA_NM) AS MAX_DATE_AMT
FROM INIT
ORDER BY PRJCT_ID, RPRTG_AREA_NM, ACCT_DATE
```

| PRJCT_ID | RPRTG_AREA_NM | ACT_PLNRT_USD_AMT | ACCT_DATE | LAST_DATE | MAX_DATE_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 009RR0S | BACKLOG | 2507543 | 2022-06-30 | 2022-09-30 | 2507543 |
| 009RR0S | BACKLOG | 2507543 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-09-30 | 2507543 |
| 009RR0S | EXPENSE | 1056 | 2022-06-30 | 2022-06-30 | 1056 |
| 009RR0S | REVENUE | 21120 | 2022-06-30 | 2022-06-30 | 21120 |
| 009RR0S | SIGNINGS | -202540 | 2021-01-31 | 2022-01-31 | -266500 |
| 009RR0S | SIGNINGS | -266500 | 2022-01-31 | 2022-01-31 | -266500 |
| 00GRQ6W | COST | 17169 | 2021-01-31 | 2021-02-28 | -17169 |
| 00GRQ6W | COST | -17169 | 2021-02-28 | 2021-02-28 | -17169 |